# Access the user utterance(first) which triggers the bot(lambda function) in Python aws lex?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am using python 2.7 trying to achieve the user utterance so after I can prompt it back to user.
I tried

```
mess = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['drink']['inputTranscript']
```

I want to access the user utterance(current utterance), example "can i order pizza".

I am using python 2.7 aws lambda.
How can i get this utterance?

My code:

```
import os
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    logger.debug('event.bot.name={}'.format(event['bot']['name']))

    return dispatch(event)

def dispatch(intent_request):
    intent_name = intent_request['currentIntent']['name']
    #prompt = intent_request['currentIntent']['inputTranscript']
    if intent_name == 'BurgerType':
        return get_burger(intent_request)

    if intent_name == 'drinks':
        return get_drink(intent_request)

def get_drink(intent_request):

    slot = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']
    value2 = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['drink']
    mess = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['drink']['inputTranscript']
    session_attributes = {}

    return close(

        session_attributes,
        'Fulfilled',{
            'contentType':'PlainText',
            'content':'Your order of 000'+mess
        })

def get_burger(intent_request):

    slots = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']
    value = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['Burgers']
    #value2 = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['cheese']
    session_attributes = {}

    return close(
        session_attributes,
        'Fulfilled',{
            'contentType': 'PlainText',
            'content':'Your order of '+value+' burger '#+value2+'has been placed'
        })

def close(session_attributes, fulfillment_state, message):
    response = {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction':{

            'type':'Close',
            'fulfillmentState': fulfillment_state,
            'message': message
        }  
    }

    return response
```

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Can you add some code to the question?

Comment: code is down below in answer section.i want to access the user utterance in python aws lambda .how can i access the user utterance ?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the below example request, the utterance by the user i.e the user input is stored in 'inputTranscript' in the 'intent_request' object.

```
{
    'messageVersion': '1.0', 
    'invocationSource': 'DialogCodeHook', 
    'userId': 'some_user_id', 
    'sessionAttributes': {}, 
    'requestAttributes': None, 
    'bot': 
        {'name': 'bot_name', 
        'alias': '$LATEST', 'version': '$LATEST'
        }, 
    'outputDialogMode': 'Text', 
    'currentIntent': 
        {
            'name': 'intent_name', 
            'slots': 
            {
                'slot1': 'value1'
            }, 
        'slotDetails': 
        {
            'slot1': 
            {
                'resolutions': [], 
                'originalValue': 'value1'
            }
        }, 
        'confirmationStatus': 'None'
        }, 
    'inputTranscript': 'what am i saying to this chatbot'
}
```

So you can access it using below code:

```
mess = intent_request['inputTranscript']
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 Pointing out InputTranscript helps solve a big problem I was currently having, where Lex takes values out of the user input and places them in slotDetails but not in actually slots.